# On input while maxlength is active trigger even if maxlength is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

"On input while maxlength is active trigger even if maxlength is reached", it is the classic use of on input event. I could set the event to false when maxlength is reached but I dont find this very clean.

Is there any other way to not trigger onInput while maxlength is reached? Maybe another event, onChange obviously doesnt works as it needs to lose input focus.

A simple jsfiddle to show my "problem" : 
`fiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/ysC7L/195/
On the third textbox, i'd like my onInput(or something else) to not trigger.

Comment: The `input` event fires no matter what the content length is, so you have two options: Remove your event handler (which you don’t want, and which is probably bad because you would need to listen to another event to know when to add it again), or chose the not _process_ it any further within your own handler function(s) when the maxlength is reached.

Comment: You cannot prevent the event from triggering, but you can control the event propagation. Bind two handler to the `input` event in specific order. The first handler controls whether or not to propagate the event(based on maxlength) and the second one can handle the event when its not maxlength.

Comment: I think I get what you both say.
Thing is I need to trigger the event when maxlength is just reached ("ab" to "abc" on maxlength = 3, it need to trigger, but "abc" => "abc" should not).
So I can't check for input length inside the event itself, because it could need to be triggered. The double event could work if I check in first if I have to trigger the second based on precedent value. Already thank, i'll be back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may need to store a reference to the previous value of the input. If you are setting the event handler on the input in the scope of a larger function, you could store the previous value of the input in a variable and compare that to the current value.

If you are setting these event handlers in the global context, you probably want to avoid storing the previous value as a global variable. Instead, you could set an attribute on the HTML input element itself to keep track of the previous value. Here's an example:

```
$('#input-5').on('input', function() {
    var self = $(this),
        prevValue = self.attr('data-prev-value') || '',
        currentValue = self.val(),
        maxLength = self.attr('maxlength');

    if (prevValue.length !== currentValue.length || prevValue.length !== maxLength) {
        // do processing
    }
    self.attr('data-prev-value', currentValue);
});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysC7L/203/.

Comment: Funny, I just did this yesterday before sleeping and I came here to post it. Thanks a lot anyway, this is the solution I  choose. I have some other trouble with cordova and maxlength on input but its another problem.

Comment: as long as you're keeping the old value - you don't really need to compare the lengths of everything. It's enough to check if self.val() != prevValue